# How to split and recombine stdout pipe in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, stdout

I am parsing text on the command line. How can I take the output of one command and use it in two places in the next command?

```
some_command | head -n $( awk '/search_term/ {print FNR} output_of_some_command ) output_of_some_command
```

I am truncating the output of `some_command` using `head`, but I need to search the output of `some_command` (using `awk` in this case) to find the line number at which to truncate.

Can I do this, or do I need to write to a temporary file?

Comment: Thinking this through I could use `sed` instead of `head` to truncate the text... but I still wonder if it could be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular task, you could use `sed` instead of `head`
– or you could use `awk` instead of `head`:

```
some_command | awk '{print} /search_term/{exit}'
```

Print lines, but, when you find one that matches the search term, exit
(and don’t process any more lines after that).

A more general solution to the problem you describe is

```
some_command | tee >(command2) | command3
```

or

```
some_command | tee >(command2) >(command3)
```

These will work in `bash`, but probably not too many other shells (including `sh`). 
`>(command)` gives you a file handle to a pipe to a process running *`command`*. 
As you probably know, `tee` lets you take a data stream and write it multiple places.

But your problem is subtlety more complicated than what you said. 
You’re not trying to do

[image: A→B and A→C in parallel]

you’re trying to do

[image: A→B→C and A→C in parallel]

where the `head` command (corresponding to `C` in the diagram)
takes input from “`some_command`” (`A`)
but also has a command-line argument set from the output of `awk` (`B`). 
I suspect that a general solution for that would be *much* trickier.